# Receiving (my app name) isn't responding right now. Please try again soon, when deploy with cloud funtions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

Receiving [my app name] isn't responding right now. Please try again soon, on Actions on google's simulator, I don't know why but when I try to run it locally, everything works just fine, it happens only when I deployed it with cloud functions

Comment: Can you please share your code which you are trying to deploy? You can also try deploying  it in Cloud Terminal using [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy) with the `--verbosity=debug` flag that provides detailed logs.

Comment: @ Rajeev Tirumalasetty I just knew the problem, the problem is I got the permission denied on cloud functions

Comment: If you already found the solution, can you please post it as an answer for better visibility to the other community members?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import everything you want, for example if want to use table etc. you must import it

```
const { dialogflow , SimpleResponse, Permission, Suggestions , Table, 
LinkOutSuggestion} = require('actions-on-google');
```

check your webhook and you payment method